# Displaying customised Item in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have created a (slightly) extended Checkbox that has an IsError property (basically used to change the colour of the checkbox to red when some condition is not met) as follows:

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsError", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCheckBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public MyCheckBox() : base()
    {
        IsError = false;
        IsCorrect = false;
    }

    public bool IsError
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsErrorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsErrorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This control is associated with the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,8,2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

All is well, if I create one of these checkboxes the it responds to the IsError binding correctly.

The issue I'm having is when placing these inside an ItemsControl.  If I create a very basic items control and set the values manually then it works - the list of items is displayed and the IsError and IsChecked properties act as expected.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0">
    <local:MyCheckBox Content="Item1"/>
    <local:MyCheckBox Content="Item2" IsChecked="True"/>
    <local:MyCheckBox Content="Item3" IsError="True"/>
    <local:MyCheckBox Content="Item4" IsChecked="True" IsError="True"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

If, however I use binding for the list of items then the Content and IsChecked properties work as expected, but the IsError property is completely ignored, I cannot get the border to change to red.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0">
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyCheckBox Content="{Binding Path=ColorName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPresent}" IsError="{Binding Path=IsError}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I know that the IsError binding value is correct (I tested by including a Label bound to the same value which displayed the correct True/False information) but I cannot work out how to get the customised Checkbox to display properly; it's as if the displayed item is using a standard Checkbox instead of the customised version.

For reference, the list of items the control is bound to is as follows:

```
public class Thing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    private string colorName;
    public string ColorName 
    {
        get { return colorName; }
        set { colorName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ColorName"); } 
    }

    private bool isPresent;
    public bool IsPresent
    {
        get { return isPresent; }
        set { isPresent = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsPresent"); }
    }

    private bool isError;
    public bool IsError
    {
        get { return isError; }
        set { isError = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsError"); } 
    }

    public CastorClip(string colorName)
    {
        ColorName = colorName;
        IsPresent = false;
        IsError = false;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Thing> myThings = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
public ObservableCollection<Thing> MyThings
{
    get { return myThings; }
    set { myThings = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MyThings"); }
}
```

What am I missing?  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a problem in the constructor of the custom checkbox where the IsError property was being set overwriting the binding expression. I'll let the other possibilities here also so that other people that did get into these common traps of WPF can check them right away.

The property IsError is not bound two way by default, change the:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(false)
```

to:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata {
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
    DefaultValue = false
}
```

Also, add this to the static constructor of your checkbox so that it will seek a default style specific to your checkbox:

```
static MyCheckBox ()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata (typeof (MyCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (typeof (MyCheckBox)));
}
```

Be sure to check how the resource is being added to your app.

Comment: I have tried changing the IsError to using two way binding by default as above and by changing the Mode to TwoWay in the XAML, but there is no change, the value is getting through to the ItemsControl (I can see the value by using a Label), but the trigger on the MyCheckBox does not seem to get called.

Comment: Yeah, it is not recognizing the the custom style as the default one, also, be sure to check how the style is being added to the app resources.

Comment: If I add the static constructor then the CheckBoxes are not displayed at all.  I have found that if I change the IsError value from within a event handler linked to the checkbox then the error event does occur (I set the IsError value directly from the Checked event, and clear in the Unchecked event), but if I make the change to IsError from the viewmodel code then nothing happens.

Comment: That's actually a good sign, when you add the static constructor, you force the system look for a style specific to your control and if it doesn't find it, nothing is displayed at all... that's why before it looks like a normal checkbox, it didn't find your style and so it uses the default one. it looks like your not merging it right in the App.xaml. post how and where you are defining the style

Comment: The MyCheckBox style is included above, it's defined in the Windows.Resources section of the application, but I've tried moving it to the Application.Resources and it makes not difference.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the project? I'm going to see it in my machine, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86571/discussion-between-timrorr-and-alexandre-borela).

Comment: Alexandre found that this problem came down to the setting of the fields in the constructor of the MyCheckBox, once the two lines were removed the issue went away.